# can someone manipulate what text shows up on the screen when google shows some examples of addresses that are available?

Tags: privacy, android, google

I started a new Google account and when I typed in a username/email address that I wanted to create I was told that the email address I had chosen was already in use and I was given an example alternative that was available. The first  username/email I entered into the field was 
GrantmetheSerenity. I was given a message that this username was already in use and an example alternative username was given. The first alternative username I was given was grantmetheserenity187@gmail.com.

I thought it was interesting that the numbers 187 would be given in the example alternative username because these numbers are notoriously known for being the police code for a homicide. That being said, this has happened to me many times before ( the numbers 187 appearing in an example alternative username).

The whole reason I created a new account was to try to spot any strange things on my new phone because I believe that I am under surveillance at least part time by an unknown entity.

Can a person or persons manipulate or control what shows up on my screen when I am given an example alternative username after typing one that is already in use? I am using a Samsung Galaxy Express 3 Android smartphone.

Comment: From a quick test, it just randomly selects numbers. In trying about 50 usernames, the only number I got multiple times was 412, and none of the names tried were Pittsburg related. Sounds like confirmation bias.

Comment: The problem is that this entity would not just have to manipulate what is shown on your screen, but would have to actually manipulate the email address *on Google*.

Comment: *That being said, this has happened to me many times before* Please provide actual information. This could just be [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias)

Answer (score 3):

Not likely. Under normal circumstances this username is generated on one of Google's servers and transported securely to your client.

Of course if your phone has malware it can show anthing, but in that case it is unlikely that only the seemingly random number is changed.

I think you are the victim of [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) or [attribution bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribution_bias). 187 is just a random number, but you interpret it in such a way as to confirm your suspicions.